# Regexp find matches inside group

Tags: regex

I want to match `<pre></pre>` tags than match `\\n` and replace matched `\\n` with `</pre><pre>`.

So I want to match a list with `[one, two, three, four, five, six]` and substitute it with `<pre>one</pre><pre>two</pre> etc.`

Input:

```
<pre> one 
two 
three 
four 
five 
six </pre>
```

Output:

```
<pre>one</pre><pre>two</pre><pre>three</pre><pre>four</pre><pre>five</pre><pre>six</pre>
```

`(?<=<pre>)?(.*)\n+`

But if I remove first `<pre>` tag it mathces anyway but it should't

Comment: What is your regex flavor or tool for this?

Comment: Making a lookaround optional totally negates the point, since you match whether or not the lookaround is found.

Comment: @anubhava any regex-directed engine

Comment: @Bob, different tools use different regex engines, which have different flag support, different ways to indicate them, different capabilities... (for instance, some don't support variable width look behind assertions), ... so it seems a relevant question to answer.

Comment: The answer will depend on which regex tool or host language you are using. Many basic regex tools have no way to match across line boundaries. Please review the [`regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for further details and guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for search with `\G`:

```bash
(?:<pre>|(?!\A)\G) *(\S*) *(?:(?<!<\/pre>)\n|<\/pre>)(?=[\s\S]*?<\/pre>)
```

and replace with:

```bash
<pre>$1</pre>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3SOxP0/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `<pre>`: Match `<pre>`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!\A)\G`:
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `*(\S*) *`: Match 0 or more non-whitespace characters and capture then in group #1. It may be surrounded with 0 or spaces on either side
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?<!<\/pre>)\n`: Match a line break if it is not preceded by closing  `</pre>`
  - `|`: OR
  - `<\/pre>`: Match `</pre>`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `(?=[\s\S]*?<\/pre>)` positive lookahead to assert presence of `</pre>`

Comment: Your approach is not exactly a working solution. If you remove `</pre> ` it will continue to match which is not what I expect.

Comment: ok try my updated answer now. In general parsing HTML with regex is not recommended because we can always find loopholes to break.

Comment: with some twiks I managed to make it work BUT it did not help in my case anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a look ahead assertion for a `</pre>` without passing over a `<pre>`.

Some precautions depending on the environment you use for defining the regex:

- The `.` may not capture a new line character. This behaviour can usually be altered with the `s` flag, or else you can use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` to really match any character.
- A slash might need to be escaped.

Proposed regex:

```
\n(?=(?:(?!<pre>)[\s\S])*<\/pre>)
```

This assumes that every `</pre>` matches with a preceding `<pre>`, and that these tags are not nested.

Answer (score 2):

Most languages provide a way to use a function to perform a regexp replacement; examples are Python, PHP, and JavaScript. So you replace the match for `<pre></pre>` using a function that removes the original tags and wraps `<pre>...</pre>` around each line.

In Python this would be:

```
def add_pre(match):
    lines = re.sub(r'\s*</?pre>\s*', '', match.group())
    return re.sub(r'^.*$', r'<pre>\g<0></pre>', lines, flags=re.MULTILINE)

text = re.sub(r'<pre>.*?</pre>', add_pre, text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand right, you want to wrap each line with `<pre></pre>` while also removing the `\n`s so your result is a single line.

My approach is to break the string in three parts:

- Beginning of the string: Leading spaces with a possible `<pre>`. The idea is to always include a `<pre>` while substituting, so it's easier to remove it first in case it's already there.
- The content of the string which you'll keep.
- The end of the string: trailing spaces and a possible `</pre>`, and a possible `\n`. This will all be replaced with a `</pre>`.

My proposed regex is `(^\s*(<pre>)?\s*)(.*?)(\s*(<\/pre>)?\s*$\n?)`. The group which you'll want to keep is `$3`, so you have to substitute each match with `<pre>$3<\/pre>`.